# Django, Deferred Attribute Error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am in a ListView that is named `PortfolioView`.  I am trying to retrieve all the items that a user has entered into the model, which is named "Prospect".  To do this, I try the following:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    Prospect.objects.all().filter(owner__username=self.request.user)
    context = MakeGraphs(Prospect.psuccess, Prospect.hc_type)
    return super(PortfolioView, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

However, when I run the function `MakeGraphs` I get an error saying that the operation cannot be ran on a Deferred Attribute.  I don't understand why it is getting returned as a Deferred Attribute.

Suggestions?

Edit: For clarity, here is an approximation of what I am doing in the `MakeGraphs` function:

```
def MakeGraphs(psuccess, hctype):
    #This isn't what I am really doing, but this should give you a flavor for it...
    newoutput1 = []
    newoutput1 = []
    for i in range(len(psuccess)):
        newoutput1.append(psuccess[i]**2 + hctype[i])
        newoutput2.append(psuccess[i]***3 + hctype[i]**2)

    aaa = sum(newoutput1)
    bbb = sum(newoutput2)

    return {'aaa':aaa, 'bbb':bbb}
```

So, It takes in a list for both variables, and returns a single value for each of the returned variables.

Edit 2:
When I use the query:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    a = Prospect.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).first()
```

I get the values for the first record where owner=user, as expected.  However, I would like to get all the values of psuccess and hc_type...

if I try this:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    a = Prospect.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

I get a 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'psuccess' error...

Edit 3:
For attributes that have a single value returned, or where you have multiple attributes returned, and you can use them one at a time instead of all at once, the answer marked as the solution will work.

However, if you need all of the values for each attribute in the form of a list you should use this for the query:
yourvar = list(MyModel.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).values_list('yourvar'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `Prospect` object instance. Model field attributes are "Deferred Attributes".

i.e

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    prospect = Prospect.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).first()
    if prospect:
        graphs = MakeGraphs(prospect.psuccess, prospect.hc_type)  # This should return a dict.
        context.update(graphs)
    return context
```

Comment: I think that this line ```Prospect.objects.all().filter(owner__username=self.request.user)``` should be replaced with ```Prospect.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)```
Thanks :)

Comment: Didn't see that error just thought the queryset was correct. updated thanks

Comment: @jackotonye when I use the .first() method it returns the first occurrence.  is there a way to get it to return all of the occurrences (I tried replacing .first() with .all(), but that doesn't seem to work)

Comment: @user1563247 can you specify what you `MakeGraphs` class code looks like if you want to pass in all the objects that should generate a dict that can be added to context. To get all objects you don't need `.all()` `.filter()` returns a queryset of all matching objects and you can iterate over them i.e `Model.object.filter(is_active=True)`